# regressing on functions with steps (Python/R)

Tags: python, r, regression, glm

As the title suggests I want to be able to perform a regression (not just a simple optimization) on the following (a non linear step function) either in R or in Python (the problem is crucial so I am willing to use whichever software gets the job done):

https://beta.postimg.org/image/3pqj0zb1b/

or in

`Y = alpha + beta * Dummy_1 + error_term

      where Dummy_1 = 1 if x > gamma * f(x) and if x < theta * f(x)
      Parameters: alpha, beta, gamma, theta`

So I want to use the powerful tools statistics puts in use and, hopefully through a GLM, compute all the nice things this model provides (I don't care about optimization problems regarding reliability yet so I'll gladly take whatever works). Unfortunately, I have no idea how to set up such a particular problem - either in R or in Python.

How would you go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for you is `scipy`
One my example code

```
import xlrd
import matplotlib.pyplot
import pylab
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import math

cord = xlrd.open_workbook('MT_coordenadas_todas.xls')

id1 = cord.sheet_by_index(0)
values1 = id1.col_values(0)

id2 = cord.sheet_by_index(0)
values2 = id2.col_values(1)

id3 = cord.sheet_by_index(0)
values3 = id3.col_values(2)

print type(values3)

a1= values1[1:16]

a2= values2[1:16]
print a2

a3= values3[1:16]
print a3

slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(a2,a3)

print slope
print intercept
```

Then you get slope and interface

```
-1.76630044629
10061774.6817
```